# How to measure the time-complexity (Big-O) of this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I'm attempting to measure the big-O complexity of the following algorithm:

```
int sumSome(int[] arr){
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<arr.length;  i++) {
      for (int j=1; j<arr.length; j = j*2) {
         if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            sum += arr[i];
      }
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Now from my understanding,

```
if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                sum += arr[i];
```

has  big O of O(1) since it's constant and nothing is happening however, the for loop that sounds it though I'm having a hard time attempting to discern its Big-O notation. I assumed that

```
for (int j=1; j<arr.length; j = j*2) {
         if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            sum += arr[i];
}
```

is a linear function O(n) because j maybe 1 but it's going up in a linear fashion at O(2n) which is just O(n). So wouldn't the entire algorithm be O(n^2)? Apparently I didn't answer the question correctly on a MOOC exam. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how you got `2n`. If anything it would be `n/2` (not that it matters to Big-O)

Comment: Of course, `n/2` is actually for `j = j+2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to Big-O is looking for loops, so your key piece is here:

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length;  i++) {
   for (int j=1; j<arr.length; j = j*2) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[j])
         sum += arr[i];
   }
}
```

The outer loop executes N times, since it goes from 0 to N in increments of 1.

The inner loop executes Log N times, per outer iteration, because it does from 1 to N exponentially. (The piece you missed, I suspect, is the iterator in the loop: `j = j*2`. This makes J increase exponentially, not linearly, so it'll reach N in log-base-2 time. It would be linear if it was `+2`, instead of `*2`)

The if inside doesn't matter for Big-O, as it only adds a coefficient.

So, just multiply the orders of the loops: `N * Log N = N Log N`

Comment: Excellent explanation, Thanks! I don't know which one to mark a the best answer wish I could do both, but since you answered first...

Answer (score 7):

> is a linear function O(n) because j maybe 1 but it's going up in a linear fashion at O(2n) which is just O(n). So wouldn't the entire algorithm be O(n^2). Apparently I didn't answer the question correctly on a MOOC exam. Thanks!

It's not going up linearly, but exponentially, because you multiply `j` by `2` at each iteration.

```
j = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ..., 2^k < n
2^k < n | apply log base 2 => k < log_2 n => k = O(log n)
```

So the second loop is only executed `O(log n)` times, making the entire sequence of code `O(n log n)`.

Strictly speaking, `O(n^2)` is also a correct answer, because if `O(n log n)` is an upper bound, then so is `O(n^2)`. Big Theta of `n^2` would not be correct however, and people usually also use Big-Oh to refer to tight bounds.

Comment: What does this mean?: *if O(n log n) is an upper bound, then so is O(n^2)*. Upper bound?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I got it. Since we're talking about Big O, then `O(log n)` would actually be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @dabadaba note the definition of big-oh (a bit simplified): if `f(x) = O(g(x))`, then `|f(x)| <= |c*g(x)|` for big enough `x`. So if `g` multiplied by a constant is always bigger than `f`. So `g` bounds `f` above, so is an upper bound. That is what I meant. `O(log n) = O(n) = O(n^2)`, yes (read the `=` as `belongs to`).